# "Perf top" sorting doesn't appear to sort at all

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

I wanted to inspect some metrics of a buffering queue and sort entries shown by `perf top` according to the number of items queued in the buffer at any given trace point.

However, when I specified the number-of-items field as the primary sort key, it didn't sort according to this key at all. As an example, I use the `net:net_dev_xmit` static trace point and the following command

> perf top -e net:net_dev_xmit -s len,overhead

The output after a few seconds of playing with the web-browser is the following

> ```
> Samples: 208  of event 'net:net_dev_xmit', Event count (approx.): 155
> Overhead         len
> 0,65%            232
> 0,65%            214
> 0,65%            192
> 0,65%            183
> 5,16%           1432
> 0,65%            152
> ```

As can be seen, it doesn't sort according to `overhead` anymore, as per my request. But it didn't sort according to `len` either! At least there's no apparent total order in the output.

At some point, I suspected that it might use alphanumeric descending order, but that's not the case either because 1432 is printed before 152, but alphanumeric descending sorting would order the prefix `14` after prefix `15`.

What's going on here?

Comment: I don't think you can sort by `len`. Try `perf top -e net:net_dev_xmit -s overhead`.

Comment: @Hadi but why is it possible to specify it as a sort key, then?

Comment: The sorting switch only works on keys that `perf` has built-in knowledge of. This includes the overhead key, but not len. I think if you specify an unsupported key, `perf` will just ignore it or it seems that it's ignoring the whole sorting switch.

Comment: Actually, can you try `perf top -e net:net_dev_xmit -s overhead,len`? That is, switch `len` and `overhead`. I expect this to sort only by the overhead.

Comment: @HadiBrais thanks, I see. Interestingly, one *cannot* specify the key on `--fields`, which is just the opposite of what I would have expected in such a case (accept for --fields, and reject for --sort). Re the switching: yes, that's the default behavior, but it's not what I want, because it wouldn't sort for len, but for overhead.

Comment: After taking a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/util/sort.c#L2505), it seems to me it's not really ignored but rather `perf` doesn't know how to sort `len`. I think `add_dynamic_entry` is called to add `len`. Using `perf-config` might potentially fix the issue.

Comment: Didn't find a solution either, after checking [perf-top man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-top.1.html), and [perf-report man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html). Maybe you can dump raw, and pipe yourself with a `sort` command? Did you try `--no-children` option? Or maybe define yourself a graph (`-g` option) and implement the `sort` function.